# Resize all containing elements with javascript utilizing em

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a situation where I think using the 'em' metric would be perfect. I have a container with several elements inside. These elements all use em for dimensions, font-size, borders.. everything. I want to be able to grow or shrink all of these elements dynamically by simply changing the em value of the parent container.

At least that's my theory. I tried to implement something like this using jquery but it appears that everything is converted to px and changing the em has no effect on the child elements.

Here is an example:

```
<div id="parent">
     <div class="child">Text</div>
     <div class="child">Text</div>
     <div class="child">Text</div>
</div>

<style>
    #parent { font-size: 1em; }
    .child { width: 10em; height: 10em; font-size: 5em; }
</style>
```

With javascript (jquery for this example), I would like to be able to do something like this:

```
$('#parent').css('font-size', '2em') // This would make everything grow
$('#parent').css('font-size', '.5em') // This would make everything shrink
```

This line does not produce an error. However, after inspecting further it appears that everything has been converted to px value. Thus, parent em values lose their power. Here is what I mean:

After the page renders, I run these commands through the firebug console

```
$('#parent').css('font-size'); // Returns 100px (for example's sake)
$('.child:first').css('font-size'); // Returns 50px
$('#parent').css('font-size', '2em'); // This should affect all children
$('#parent').css('font-size'); // Returns 20px
$('.child:first').css('font-size'); // STILL Returns 50px
```

As you can see, all the children remain at 50px.

Am I going about this the right way? What am I missing? Is this really a lot harder than I think it is? In a sense, I'm trying to duplicate the effect that browser-zoom has.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You try resizing the text using percentage.

```
$('#parent').css('font-size', '200%')// This would make everything grow
$('#parent').css('font-size', '50%') // This would make everything shrink
```

---

edit after comment - using FF2.0

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jqueryui.com/latest/jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
    body {font-size:10px;}
    #parent { font-size: 1em; }
    .child { width: 10em; height: 10em; font-size: 5em; }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
        alert($('#parent').css('font-size')); // Returns 10px (for example's sake)
        alert($('.child:first').css('font-size')); // Returns 50px
        $('#parent').css('font-size', '200%'); // or you can use 2em here
        alert($('#parent').css('font-size')); // Returns 20px
        alert($('.child:first').css('font-size')); // Returns 100px
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="parent">
     <div class="child">Text</div>
     <div class="child">Text</div>
     <div class="child">Text</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: But is a domino effect not possible? I'd have to use this technique for all the children with every style rule that I need (width, height, font-size, border, etc). I suppose dom traversal with recursion is possible but I was hoping to avoid something like that.

Comment: It is affecting the children in my tests (ems and %).  Maybe it has something to do with running the jquery in the the firebug console. 
I will paste the code I used above.

Comment: Well I feel foolish... When I wrote my code into the page itself instead of the firebug console it worked exactly as I hoped. Thanks for your help Emily and jitter.

Answer (score 0):

The above works just fine for me in Opera, FF and IE6 (can't test others). Using these two calls do grow and shrink the text.

```
$('#parent').css('font-size', '2em');    // grows
$('#parent').css('font-size', '0.5em'); //  shrinks
```

Before I call either of those

```
alert($('#parent').css('fontSize'));      // 16px in Opera,FF,IE6
alert($('.child:first').css('fontSize')); // 80px in Opera&FF, 400px in IE6
```

After a call to say

```
$('#parent').css('font-size', '0.5em');   // shrinks
alert($('#parent').css('fontSize'));       // 0.5em in Opera,FF,IE6
alert($('.child:first').css('fontSize')); //  45px Opera, 40 px FF, 200px in IE6
```

So what browsers (version) and jQuery version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

it's great stuff, I have just switched to em-s, and was strugling to set proper heights for divs in case of font change. thanks to this post I did something like that (ps. I don't really know javascript):

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
     s=$('#parent').css('font-size');       
     s=(s.substring(0,s.length-2));
     x=s*1; //the only way I know to convert string to number
     height1=document.getElementById('div-a').offsetHeight/x;
     height2=document.getElementById('div-b').offsetHeight/x;
     if (height1>height2) {
        document.getElementById('div-b').style.height=height1+"em";
        //(...)
  }});
```